# Create new Pandas.DataFrame with .groupby(...).agg(sum) then recover unsummed columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting with a dataframe of baseabll seasons a section of which looks similar to this:

```
                   Name  Season   AB    H  SB  playerid
13047   A.J. Pierzynski    2013  503  137   1       746
6891    A.J. Pierzynski    2006  509  150   1       746
1374          Rod Carew    1977  616  239  23   1001942
1422        Stan Musial    1948  611  230   7   1009405
1507        Todd Helton    2000  580  216   5       432
1508  Nomar Garciaparra    2000  529  197   5       190
1509      Ichiro Suzuki    2004  704  262  36      1101
```

From these seasons, I want to create a dataframe of career stats; that is, one row for each player which is a sum of their AB, H, etc. This dataframe should still include the names of the players.  The playerid in the above is a unique key for each player and should either be an index or an unchanged value in a column after creating the career stats dataframe.

My hypothetical starting point is `df_careers = df_seasons.groupby('playerid').agg(sum)` but this leaves out all the non-numeric data. With `numeric_only = False` I can get some sort of mess in the names columns like 'Ichiro SuzukiIchiro SuzukiIchiro Suzuki' from concatenation, but that just requires a bunch of cleaning. This is something I'd like to be able to do with other data sets and the actually data I have is more like 25 columns, so I'd rather understand a specific routine for getting the Name data back or preserving it from the outset rather than write a specific function and use `groupby('playerid').agg(func)` (or a similar process) to do it, if possible.

I'm guessing there's a fairly simply way to do this, but I only started learning Pandas a week ago, so there are gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own condition how do you want to include non summed columns.

```
col = df.columns.tolist()
col.remove('playerid')
df.groupby('playerid').agg({i : lambda x: x.iloc[0] if x.dtypes=='object' else x.sum() for i in df.columns})
```

---

**df:**

```
           Name                 Season  AB   H      SB  playerid
playerid                        
190        Nomar_Garciaparra    2000    529  197    5   190
432        Todd_Helton          2000    580  216    5   432
746        A.J._Pierzynski      4019    1012 287    2   1492
1101       Ichiro_Suzuki        2004    704  262    36  1101
1001942    Rod_Carew            1977    616  239    23  1001942
1009405    Stan_Musial          1948    611  230    7   1009405
```

Comment: Works, but very slow for my actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a one-to-one relationship between 'playerid' and 'Name', as appears to be the case, you can just include 'Name' in the `groupby` columns:

```
stat_cols = ['AB', 'H', 'SB']
groupby_cols = ['playerid', 'Name']
results = df.groupby(groupby_cols)[stat_cols].sum()
```

Results:

```
                              AB    H  SB
playerid Name                            
190      Nomar Garciaparra   529  197   5
432      Todd Helton         580  216   5
746      A.J. Pierzynski    1012  287   2
1101     Ichiro Suzuki       704  262  36
1001942  Rod Carew           616  239  23
1009405  Stan Musial         611  230   7
```

If you'd prefer to group only by 'playerid' and add the 'Name' data back in afterwards, you can instead create a 'playerId' to 'Name' mapping as a dictionary, and look it up using `map`:

```
results = df.groupby('playerid')[stat_cols].sum()
name_map = pd.Series(df.Name.to_numpy(), df.playerid).to_dict()
results['Name'] = results.index.map(name_map)
```

Results:

```
            AB    H  SB               Name
playerid                                  
190        529  197   5  Nomar Garciaparra
432        580  216   5        Todd Helton
746       1012  287   2    A.J. Pierzynski
1101       704  262  36      Ichiro Suzuki
1001942    616  239  23          Rod Carew
1009405    611  230   7        Stan Musial
```

Comment: The total collection of data I'm working  includes some repeated names (It's every ball player since 1947.) Actually, there are some guys you've never heard of, except they share a name with a Hall of Famer. Anyway, for some reason I get ```TypeError: dict object is not callable``` when I run ```careers['Name'] = careers.index.map(name_map)```. This is making so sense to me, as map clearly takes dictionaries as arguments.

Comment: Actually thinking about it again, the first solution doesn't require a one-to-one relationship at all. If you have ID 1 = John Smith and ID 2 = John Smith, they will be in separate groups if you group by both ID and name. So I think that's the way to go here. Not sure why the second solution isn't working, just tested it again and all fine (Python 3.7.7, Pandas 1.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

groupy.agg() can accept a dictionary that maps column names to functions. So, one solution is to pass a dictionary to agg, specifying which functions to apply to each column.

Using the sample data above, one might use

```
mapping = { 'AB': sum,'H': sum, 'SB': sum, 'Season': max, 'Name': max }
df_1 = df.groupby('playerid').agg(mapping)
```

The choice to use 'max' for those that shouldn't be summed is arbitrary. You could define a lambda function to apply to a column if you want to handle it in a certain way. DataFrameGroupBy.agg can work with any function that will work with DataFrame.apply.

To expand this to larger data sets, you might use a dictionary comprehension. This would work well:

```
dictionary = { x : sum for x in df.columns}
dont_sum = {'Name': max,  'Season': max}
dictionary.update(dont_sum)
df_1 = df.groupby('playerid').agg(dictionary)
```